Python: FastAPI not accepting SQLModel as a return type on routes
I'm making an API based on the FastAPI docs (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#install-sqlmodel). I have noticed this docs are kind of deprecated due to @app.on_event("startup") decorator, which my interpreter told me need to be replaced with lifespan events (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/).
In the API docs, the model Hero is created with SQLModel and is stated to be  a valid pydantic model, using it as a return type on routes:

The Hero class is very similar to a pydantic model (in fact, underneath, it actually is a Pydantic model).

from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, Query
from sqlmodel import Field, Session, SQLModel, create_engine, select


class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    age: int | None = Field(default=None, index=True)
    secret_name: str

# Code below omitted 

# Code above omitted 

@app.post("/heroes/")
def create_hero(hero: Hero, session: SessionDep) -> Hero:
    session.add(hero)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(hero)
    return hero

# Code below omitted 

When I try to do the same, python throws this error:

fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <module 'models.Hero' from 'C:\...\Hero.py'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/

This is my project structure:
src
├── app.py
├── models
│   └── Hero.py
└── service
    └── db_config.py

With this command I mount my API:
$ uvicorn app:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080

app.y
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from service.db_config import engine, SessionDep, create_db_and_tables
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from sqlmodel import select
from models import Hero

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    print("Startup")
    create_db_and_tables()
    yield
    print("Shutdown")

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get("/")
def get_welcome_message():
    return JSONResponse(
        content={
            "message": "Welcome to my API"
        },
        status_code=200
    )

@app.post("/heroes")
def create_hero(hero: Hero, session: SessionDep) -> Hero:
    session.add(hero)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(hero)
    
    return JSONResponse(
        content=hero,
        status_code=200
    )

@app.get("/heroes")
def get_heroes(session: SessionDep, offset: int = 0, limit: Annotated[int, Query(le=100)] = 100) -> list[Hero]:
    heroes = session.exec(select(Hero).offset(offset).limit(limit)).all()
    
    return JSONResponse(
        content=heroes,
        status_code=200
    )

db_config.py
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends
from sqlmodel import Session, create_engine, SQLModel

def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session
        
def create_db_and_tables():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

db_engine = "postgresql"
db_user = "postgresql"
db_user_password = "ADMIN"
db_address = "127.0.0.1"
db_name = "realm"
connect_args = {"check_same_thread": False}
db_url = f"{db_engine}://{db_user}:{db_user_password}@{db_address}/{db_name}"

engine = create_engine(url=db_url, connect_args=connect_args)
SessionDep = Annotated[Session, Depends(get_session)]

Hero.py
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel,table

class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: str = Field(primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name: str = Field(nullable=False)
    age: int = Field(nullable=False)

How can I solve this?

Drop the explicit creation of JSONResponse - everything you need is already defined because of the return type on the controller functions.

@MatsLindh Same error persists even with that
